# Linear (in)dependence of $\sin (x), \sin (x+1), \sin (x+2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, intuition

I need to discuss the linear independence of the following given vectors: \begin{align} \sin(x), \sin(x+1), \sin(x+2)\end{align} there are many similar questions on math.SE but most of which I have looked into deal with integrals and all I have to work with is the elementary definition of linear independence:

The given vectors are considered as *linearly independent* if and only if \begin{align}\lambda_1 \sin(x)+\lambda_2\sin(x+1)+\lambda_3\sin(x+2)=0 \implies \lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=0 \end{align}
The way I have approached this now was to use the *trigonometric identities* and then simplify the result, merging the constants together. I am not sure if this is a correct workaround but here is my attempt: 
\begin{align}\lambda_1 \sin(x) + \lambda_2 (\sin(1)\cos(x)+\cos(1)\sin(x))+\lambda_3(\sin(2)\cos(x)+\cos(2)\sin(x)) \\=(\underbrace{\lambda_1+\lambda_2\cos(1)+\lambda_3\cos(2)}_{:=k_1})\sin(x)+ (\underbrace{\lambda_2 \sin(1)+\lambda_3\sin(2)}_{:=k_2})\cos(x) \end{align}
such that I can write:
\begin{align} k_1 \sin(x) + k_2 \cos(x)=0 \implies k_1=k_2=0 \end{align}
Due to the fact that $ \cos(x), \sin(x)$ are linearly independent. My problem is that I seem to have 'erased' one scalar variable with my substitution, would I need to use back substitution now and see if I can deduce $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3$ from there, or is my approach wrong from the beginning?

***Additional***:

If I can bother to ask, intuition wise the given set do not look like vectors at all to me, since I am very new to this subject I may have wait with further understanding this problem, but would one of the above vectors just look like the regular function, depending on at which point $x$ they are evaluated?

Comment: A vector is what we call a member of a vector space, whatever it might be.

Comment: "or is my approach wrong from the beginning" No, the approach is right. Maybe you should think about which result you will be able to prove.

Comment: in an earlier exercise I did already have to show that $\cos(x), \sin(x)$ are linearly independent, my goal was to reach that point again which I have managed to do by merging the constants together as demonstrated. Is this already sufficient or are there some steps left?

Comment: A different path you might think about... when we discuss function space the equations you write hold for all $x$. Thus, we can evaluate at special values of $x$ to cipher data. For example, you might think about $x=\pi$ and $x = 1-\pi$ etc..

Comment: Did you try to developp $sin(x+1+1)$ instead of $sin(x+2)$?

Comment: @Spaced Can you conclude $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = 0$ from $k_1 = k_2 = 0$, or can you maybe find some nonzero $\lambda_i$ that nevertheless produce $k_1 = k_2 = 0$?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer, for the $k_2=\lambda_2 \sin(1) + \lambda_3 \sin (2)=0$ case I could say that $\lambda_2=-\frac{1}{\sin(1)}, \lambda_3= \frac{1}{\sin(2)}$

Comment: And can you find a $\lambda_3$ to make $k_1 = 0$ then?

Comment: @DanielFischer for the case $k_1=\lambda_1 - \sec(1) + \sec(2) =0 $ I could choose $\lambda_1= \sec(1) - \sec(2)$

Comment: So, linearly independent, or dependent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand $\sin(x+1)$ and $\sin(x+2)$ using the identity for $\sin(\alpha+\beta)$.  You will find that the three "vectors" $\sin(x)$, $\sin(x+1)$ , and $\sin(x+2)$ are all linear combinations of the two "vectors" $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.  What can you conclude from that?  Try to work your conclusion into a proof using the definition of linear independence or linear dependence.

EDIT:  I'm sorry, it looks you already did most of what I suggested above.  You get a system of two linear equations that must be satisfied by the three variables $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, and $\lambda_3$.  What usually happens when you have fewer equations then variables?  Can you find a solution in which at least of one the $\lambda$'s is nonzero?

Whoever asked you the question should have specified what the vector space is.  I have to guess.  I'll guess it's the set of all continuous functions from the real numbers to the real numbers.  A "vector" is such a function.  "Vectors" are added to each other and mutliplied by scalars in the obvious manner (if this is not obvious to you, hopefully you have a text, and that text should have examples like this one).

As Git Gud wrote, to a mathematician, a "vector" is simply an element of a vector space.  Wikipedia has an article on vector spaces that begins with a long explanation, probably aimed at non-mathematicians, explaining why one might be interested in such a concept, before they get to the definition.  Unfortunately, the precise definition includes a long list of rules.  Fortunately, all of the rules are intuitively compelling, and it is hard to imagine (at least for me) why one would want a "vector space" not to satisfy any of the rules.